# Flask-SQLAlchemy - Model not found when declaring relationship

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When declaring a relationship between my two models (which are stored in two separate files, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class FrequencyBand->frequency_bands_table, expression 'LicenseItem' failed to locate a name ('LicenseItem'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'src.models.metaData.FrequencyBand'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

I thought that this problem is avoided by using the string representation (via declarative base) -> but it seems like I'm importing the FrequencyBand-Object before the mapper is setup. How can I fix that? (as a workaround I declared the relationship on the LicenseItem, but I have similar problems with other relationships). Any Ideas/Hints? Any help is highly appreciated!

```
class FrequencyBand(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "frequency_bands_table"
    band_id = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    band_nr = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    technology = db.Column(db.String(20))
    license = db.relationship("LicenseItem")
    license_id = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey('license_items_table.item_id'))

class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'items_table'
    item_id = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.Enum("Antennen", "Radio", "Diverses", "Lizenzen"))
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    description = db.Column(db.String(100))
    otc = db.Column(db.Integer)
    mrc = db.Column(db.Integer)
    custom_price = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    item_status = db.Column(db.Enum("active", "inactive"))
    last_updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'Item',
        'polymorphic_on':category
    }
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MiscellaneousItem(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity':'Diverses'}
    __tablename__ = 'miscellaneous_items_table'
    item_id = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('items_table.item_id'), primary_key=True)

class MiscellaneousItemSchema(marshmallow.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = MiscellaneousItem
        include_fk = True

class AntennaItem(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity':'Antennen'}
    __tablename__ = 'antenna_items_table'
    item_id = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('items_table.item_id'), primary_key=True)
    hardware_types = db.relationship("HardwareType", secondary=item_hw_type_table)
    frequency_bands = db.relationship("FrequencyBand", secondary=item_frequency_table)
    mimo_layers = db.Column(db.Integer)
    nrOfBands = db.Column(db.Integer)
    allowed_SLA_types = db.relationship("SLAType", secondary=item_sla_types_table)

class LicenseItem(Item): #Item-Subclass --> Joined table inheritance
    __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity':'Lizenzen'}
    __tablename__ = 'license_items_table'
    item_id = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('items_table.item_id'), primary_key=True)
    frequencies = db.relationship("FrequencyBand", backref="license")
```

Since I use namespaces & blueprints for my flask application, the models are imported within the namespace and the blueprints are registered via application factory pattern.

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restx import Api
from .meta_data import ns as meta_data_ns
from .projects import ns as projects_ns


api_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_blueprint)

api.add_namespace(meta_data_ns, path='/meta')
api.add_namespace(projects_ns, path='/projects')
```

```
#meta namespace -> the first namespace which is registered -> and therefore the FrequencyBand is imported before LicenseItem is declared
from flask_restx import Namespace, Resource
from src.models.metaData import FrequencyBand
from src.models.item import Item, AllItemsSchema
from src.models.utils import token_required


ns = Namespace('meta', description='Operations related to meta data')

@ns.route('/')
class UnitObject(Resource):
    @token_required
    def get(self):
    #...
```

```
#app.__init__
from flask import Flask
from .extensions import db,...
from src.config import app_config


def create_app(config_name):
    """Create and return app."""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    marshmallow.init_app(app)
    ...
    with app.app_context():
        from src.api import api_blueprint
        from src.admin_backend.commands import bp as command_bp
        app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint, url_prefix="/api")
        app.register_blueprint(command_bp)
        return app
```

Comment: Can you please post the Item class? Without the Item class your code is working for me.

Comment: thanks for your support. I added the Item class. I also realised that db is referencing flask_sqlalchemy (and not sqlalchemy but I understood that those two should be identical). But maybe the Joined table inheritance is causing some problems?

Answer (score 0):

In the class `FrequencyBand` the attribute `license` is responsible for the error.

```py
    license = db.relationship("LicenseItem")  # throws error
```

You have to delete this line and declare it at a later point, i.e. doing exactly what the error message said. For example:

```py
  # FrequencyBand is imported before LicenseItem is declared
  from flask_restx import Namespace, Resource
  from src.models.metaData import FrequencyBand
  from src.models.item import Item, AllItemsSchema
  from src.models.utils import token_required

  FrequencyBand.license = db.relationship("LicenseItem")
```

This isn't a very elegant solution, but might be right for this specific use case (I really can't say).

The problem arises because you have two dependent relationships in your classes. If you just want to declare a Many-to-Many relationship please check out the [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships) on using a helper table.